# Need every name in the list to query active directory

Tags: string, powershell, foreach, split, line

Why does this only display the last object and not all of them for each loop?

```
$str = @"
First1 Last1
First2 Last2
First3 Last3
First4 Last4
"@

foreach ($line in $str.Split("`n")) {
    $userOBJ = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $line} 
    $userOBJ
}
```

Output Only has one record.

```
DistinguishedName : CN=First Last,OU=BLAH and BLAH,OU=BLAH BLAH,DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com
Enabled           : True
GivenName         : First
Name              : First Last
ObjectClass       : user
ObjectGUID        : XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXX
SamAccountName    : useranme
SID               : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Surname           : Last
UserPrincipalName : username@comain.com
```

Comment: Windows line endings, possibly.  Try `Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $line.Trim() }`  Alternately, try `$str.Split("\`r\`n")`.

Comment: Get-ADUser : Property: 'Trim' not found in object of type: 'System.String'.

Comment: Just a comment after the fact, the `.Trim()` method works fine if you sub-expression it, such as: `Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like $($line.Trim()) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = @"
First1 Last1
First2 Last2
First3 Last3
First4 Last4
"@

#Split your string and remove empty/null values.
$Names = $str.Split("`r`n") | ? { $_ }

#Make one filter request with all your names.
$Filter = "Name -like '$($Names -Join "' -or Name -like '")'"

Get-ADUser -Filter $Filter
```

Making one request to AD with many filters will improve speed and less overhead for your domain controller.

**CLARIFICATION ON HOW TO CREATE YOUR FILTER**

When wanting to build a long filter with multiple search results, you need to format your filter this way:

```
$Filter = "Name -Like 'First1 Last1' -or Name -Like 'First2 Last2' -or Name 'First3 Last3' -or Name -Like 'First4 Last4'"
```

The easiest way is to do a join, with whatever you would have in-between each value inside your array. In this case `' -or Name -Like '` is between each value in $Names.

```
$JoinResult = $Names -Join "' -or Name -Like '"
```

$JoinResult -eq :

```
First1 Last1' -or Name -Like 'First2 Last2' -or Name 'First3 Last3' -or Name -Like 'First4 Last4
```

Next step is to cap it off.. (the start and the end to that filter string) You want your filter to start with `Name -Like '` and finish with the trailing `'`

```
$Filter = "Name -Like '$JoinResult'"
```

And doing all this in one line is:

```
$Filter = "Name -like '$($Names -Join "' -or Name -like '")'"
```

Comment: Curious could you explain this code? `'$($Names -Join "' -or Name -like '")'`

Comment: You want the following sting pattern: (Name -Like '$name`') -or (Name -Like '`$name`') -or (Name -Like '`$name') and so on..  Do you see the pattern? So joining each $name in $names with this pattern in between, makes one nice big filter string.. ;)

Comment: The beauty is, if there is only 1 name in $names, it won't put the pattern in between, and simply output the $name..

Comment: OIC if the name had a leading or trailing space or name in the list? Like Mr. First Last or First Last Jr. Am I on the right track? So you are looking for the pattering inside the string?

Comment: Updated my answer with more step by step on how to build a long filter query from an array. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($line in $str -Split('\r\n')) {
Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -eq $line} 
}
```

Adding the -Split and the \r fixed my issue. Thank you @gbabu and @Bacon Bits for leading me in the right direction.